# Regex - return only first src url match

Tags: regex, srcset

I'm trying to extract the first jpg from a page of text. multiple paragraphs and multiple urls in each, but i only want the first url/jpg, stop after first is matched/returned.

**sample page;**

this is some text and a url  src="https://www.someurl.jpg" more text, more text, more text.
more text, more text

more text, more text.
this is some text and a url  src="https://www.anotherurl.jpg" more text, more text, more text.
more text, more text.

**Current Code;**

```
(?<=src=")(.*?)(?=")
```

This code returns both urls.  I need the output to be just the first one it finds and stop there, just return the first.

**Output required;**

https://www.someurl.jpg

any help appreciated.

Comment: `.match( /.../ )?.[0]` ?

Comment: How about this, `src="[^"]+"`, https://regex101.com/r/5DwzA3/1. Don't forget to use the global flag, so it doesn't return after the first match

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is quite good, just add surroundings and **g** flag.
/(?<=src=")(.*?)(?=")/g
Now You gave correct regex.

```js
console.log(`I'm trying to extract the first jpg from a page of text. multiple paragraphs and multiple urls in each, but i only want the first url/jpg, stop after first is matched/returned.

sample page;

this is some text and a url src="https://www.so23123123123l.jpg" more text, more text, more text. more text, more text

more text, more text. this is some text and a url src="https://www.anotherurl.jpg" more text, more text, more text. more text, more text.`.match(/(?<=src=")(.*?)(?=")/ig));
```

You can read [here](https://www.codeguage.com/courses/regexp/flags) about regexp flags.

Comment: hey, thanks for the response.  not sure if this works.  in my sample text there are 2 urls, i want to return the first one only.   (in the actual page i'm extracting from there are possible 4 or 5 in content encoded block, but again only require the first matching url).

Comment: You can check using my code snippet . 
Could You show some more representative example ?
And do You prefer some function, like match or matchAll or exec ?